# XMLHttpRequest cannot load local destop file in html

Tags: javascript, html, macos

I have an json file in my desktop folder and i try to access in my html file but i get following error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://localhost/Users/p41technologies/Desktop/Json%20in%20Html/json-data.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I even tryied to,

> open -a "Google Chrome" --args --allow-files-access-from-files

and

> open -a "Google Chrome" --disable-web-security

but it didn't work. I still get the same error.
Why does it happen and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

the security feature you encountered is supposed to prevent malicious scripts to read from the local file system.

have you looked into the [html5 file/filereader api](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)? there is a [tutorial with working demos](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). you may also have a look [here](http://html5demos.com/file-api-simple).